# Companion ria keeps attacking me causing all others to attack

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm not sure what I did to Ria in the companions but she has no armor on and every time I go and try to progress through the story, she tries to kill me and then every other companion starts to attack me as well. How do I end this? I am on PS3 so I can't do any commands or stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about what caused this, so I can't help you there.
However, I do know several possible fixes.

1. Use Calm spell or something similar on them.
2. If you are an Imperial (race), use Voice of the Emperor.
3. If you have the Dragonborn DLC, and have gotten the first 2 words to the Bend Will Shout, use that shout; however, you will have to make sure you hit everybody with it, because otherwise the ones you hit will turn and attack the ones you didn't.
4. This is a LAST RESORT! Restart your game and make sure you do not steal from the Companions, and that you do nothing to make Ria mad!

Answer (score 0):

Have you attacked her first, or any other Companion? If so, this might happen. If you have a bounty, then you need to get rid of it. If the Companion leaders aren't attacking, talk to them, and if they say you've done a crime with the option to pay the bounty, pay it.

If they do however, attack you, find a guard and if he tells you you've committed a crime, pay the bounty or go to jail, or otherwise, leave your dead body out in the streets of Whiterun.

Otherwise, you can either go to a place where there are no NPCs attacking, and go to another city (Your bounty is separate for each Hold. Example: If you have a bounty in Whiterun, but have not committed a crime in The Rift, you'll be safe in The Rift Hold). Wait for a few hours and then come back to see if they are no hostile.

You can also exit out of the game and reenter the game again.

<strike>You may also use commands to change your bounty and the Companions' actions.</strike>